# Does jQuery have a method for checking all values of an array to see if they meet some criteria?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm looking for something similar to Groovy's [every()](http://groovy.codehaus.org/groovy-jdk/java/lang/Object.html#every%28%29) method, which tests every element of a list if it meets some criteria.  If they all meet the criteria, the function returns true.  Otherwise, false.  I've tried something like this:

```
var arr = [1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1];
var allOnes = $.grep(arr, function(ind) { 
                   return this == 1;
               }).length == arr.length;
```

..but its not very clean.  I haven't had any luck while searching through the API.  Is using `grep()` the only way to do it?

Comment: why would you want to use jQuery for something like this? it's not like iterating over an array is browser-specific :)

Comment: True, its not browser specific.  But I'm creating a webpage using jQuery, and was curious if such a method existed.

Comment: @Tom Knappen: i often use `$.each()` to operate on arrays, as it is frequntly handier than a for or while loop, and it mantains consistency in the code

Comment: @Pat see update to my answer and the plugin that could be modified.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about just turning your working code into a method on array, to ease its reuse:

```
Array.prototype.every = function(predicate){
 return $.grep(this,predicate).length == this.length;  
}
```

usage:

```
alert([1,0,1,0].every(function(i) { return i == 1; }));
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/59J5A/

Edit: changed to grep

Comment: I was hoping that something like this would already be included in the framework, but this appears like it will fit the bill.  Thanks.

Comment: Something about using a jquery method in a prototype just feels wrong.

Answer (score 2):

if it is a plain js array, you have [`$.grep()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.grep/)

`.filter()` is for use with jQuery or DOM Elements

Answer (score 1):

Here is a plugin I made that might make it easier:

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.allOnes = function() {
        var allVal = true;
        this.each(function(ind, item) {
            if (item != 1) {
                allVal = false;
                return allVal;
            }
        });
        return allVal;
    };
})(jQuery);

var arr = [1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1];
console.log($(arr).allOnes());
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/NctND/

---

The following plugin is an expansion of the above and lets you search for a specific number: http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/bFNnn/

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.allValue = function(pred) {
        var allOnes = true;
        this.each(function(ind, item) {
            if (item != pred) {
                allOnes = false;
                return allOnes;
            }
        });
        return allOnes;
    };
})(jQuery);

var arr = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1];
console.log($(arr).allValue(1));
```

Comment: `.filter()` if for sets of elements, no js arrays

Comment: @Einacio -- i changed my answer.

Comment: This is nice, but I was looking for a more general solution.  I'm not always testing arrays for numeric values.  Passing in the predicate function is looking like its going to be the ideal solution.

Comment: @Pat - i just named the plugin `allNumber` but you can pass anything (just rename it, it doesn't matter what its called, I'm not verifying that the input is a number) it would work just as well with a string :-D

Comment: @Pat -- I renamed it `allValue` and it works just as well :-D

Answer (score 1):

here is example of function you can use.

```
var arr = [1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1];
var allOnes = arr.check(1);

//this function compares all elements in array and if all meet the criteria it returns true
Array.prototype.chack =  function(cond)
{
   var ln = 0;
   for(i=0; i<this.length; i++)
   {
     if(bond === this[i])
     {
       ln++
     }
   }
   if(ln == this.length)
   return true;
   else
   return false;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You could always implement an allOnes method:

```
function allOnes(array) {
    var result = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i += 1) {
        if (array[i] === 1) { result.push(true); }
    }

    return array.length == result.length;
}
```

or you could be a bit more abstract and test for true/false:

```
function all(array) {
    var result = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i += 1) {
        if (array[i]) { result.push(true); }
    }

    return array.length == result.length;
}

var arr = [1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1];
var allOnes = all(arr);
```

or even better, maybe have a changeable predicate:

```
function all(array, predicate) {
    var result = [],
        predicate = predicate || function(x) { if (x) { return true; } };

    for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i += 1) {
        if (predicate(array[i])) { result.push(true); }
    }

    return array.length == result.length;
}

var allOnes = all(arr, function(x) { return x === 1; })
```

Comment: This would work for numeric arrays, but what happens if I have an array that is composed of letters, like `[a, a, b, a]`, and I want to check to see if the array contains only `a`'s?

Comment: Look at the amended answer. You could change the predicate to function(x) { if(x === 'a') { return true; } }